# Sum from combinatorics on nonnegative integer numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, diophantine-equations

Let $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Can you calculate the sum
$$
\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k\geqslant0}\mathbb{1}_\left\{n_1+\frac{n_2}{2}+\ldots+\frac{n_k}{k}<1\right\}?
$$
If it's helpful, I can see that
$$
\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k\geqslant0}\mathbb{1}_\left\{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k<k\right\}=\binom{2k-1}{k}.
$$

Comment: For the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $n_1 + n_2/2 + \ldots + n_k/k \le 1$, see [OEIS sequence A212658](https://oeis.org/A212658).

Comment: @RobertIsrael and number of solutions for $n_1+n_2/2+...+n_k/k=1$ is [A020473](http://oeis.org/A020473), so the question is about difference of these two sequences

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments The sequence you want is the third row below.

The first gives the number of solutions where the sum is less than or equal to $1$. The initial entry is for  the empty sum when $k=0$ and the fourth entry is for $k=3$ counting the $8$ cases $0,\frac13,\frac12,\frac23,\frac12+\frac13,\frac11,\frac22,\frac33$

The second row is the cases where the sum is exactly $1$ so the $3$ below the $8$ is the things you don't want.

The difference is what you want

$\begin{array}{r}
 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 17 & 37 & 86 & 199 & 475 & 1138 & 2769 & 6748 & 16613 & 40904 & 101317 & 251401 & 624958 & 1555940 & 3882708  \\
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 13 & 14 & 24 & 34 & 60 & 61 & 168 & 169 & 252 & 627 & 1011 & 1012 & 2430\\
 &1&2&5&12&31&73 &185&451&1104&2709 &6687& 16445 &\cdots
\end{array}$

Observations:

- Allowing the variable $n_1$ is irrelevant for your particular problem since you want a sum less than $1$. Is is a matter of choice if it should be considered in counting the other two sequences. The we can have $n_1=1$ exactly once, when all the rest are $0.$
- The sequence you want is not in the OEIS (at this moment)
- The numbers in the second row are very small compared to the first row so the last thing I showed is over $98.9\%$ of the corresponding entry in the first row.
- The first sequence counts the number of lattice points in the ($k$ dimensional) right pyramid with corners at the origin and $(1,0,0,0,\cdots),(0,2,0,0,\cdots), \cdots,(0,0,\cdots,k).$ That solid has volume $1$ (or $k$ If we forget about $n_1$ and go down a dimension.)
- In the OEIS the first sequence is given up to $k=36$ with a comment that the calculations get large. The ratios of consecutive entries do increase, but rather slowly:
  $\frac{199}{86}=2.314, \frac{475}{199}=2.387$ The last three entries given $$10002686041923, 25294749317818 ,  63990381763012 $$ have ratios about $2.528795$ and $2.529789.$